# Update a current view on a with a given tab bar index.

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar

So I have a signup page and view x. Upon a successful login, I need to replace a different view at view x, which happens to the third tab bar or, 2 index in the array. I have tried:

```
[self.view insertSubview:planer.view atIndex:2];
```

I'm wondering if there is there something like:

```
[self.tabBarController insertSubview:viewX atIndex:2];
```

Hopefully I am clear for everyone.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to create container view controller which will replace child controller's view based on your's conditional requirement.

Your tab controller's root view controller will be a container view controller. Since the view will be in different view controller, it will clearly encapsulate the given view and its respective responsibility into respective view controller which will respond to all the view controller's lifecycle call back methods.

There will be a Login view controller which will deal only with login and on successfully login, it will notify its container view controller and on respective delegate callback method in the container view controller, you will add different view controller as its child and replace its view with the current container view controller's view.

Please look at the following URL for more info https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers.html